# GMSMarker hide/show in GMSMapView in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I used google map sdk for my iOS Application. Here I want to perform GMSMarker hide/show functionality based on the GMSMapView zoom in/zoom out.

Could anyone guide me in correct solution please.

Comment: I don't know, marker has the hide/show functionality. So please share your comments to archive this. In iOS MapKit sdk has the hide/show option.

Answer (score 3):

You can add UIPinchGestureRecognizer on your map view.

```
mapView_.gestureRecognizers = @[ /*add your UIPinchGestureRecognizer instance here*/];
```

Then in its selector method you can hide/show the marker using:

```
 marker.map = nil; //To hide
 marker.map = mapView_; //To show
```